# Jquery function for enabling a button based on datetime values

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a simple client side validation Jquery am working on.  I need to activate a button after a user has selected 2 different dates.

Here is a look at my form html:

```
    <form asp-action="Index">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="control-label">Arrive</label>
            <input id="datepicker1" name="Arrival" type="date" class="form-control test1" value="" />
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Depart</label>
            <input id="datepicker2" name="Depart" type="date" class="form-control test2" value="" />
            <span  class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="register" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have written a Jquery formula:

```
$("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").on('change paste keyup input', function () {
    if ($("#datepicker1").val() != '' && $("#datepicker2").val() != '') {

        $("#register").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

However it is not working as expected.  The button '#register' is being enabled after there is any input in either field. It should only activate after both fields have values and are not null. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Youve made a typo in the `if` conditions - the names are `datepicker1` and not `datetimepicker1` (same for 2). BTW this makes the `val()` equal to `undefined` which is why the button gets enabled. Fix this and it [works as I'm sure you expected](https://jsfiddle.net/12ntm369/)

Comment: Thank you for catching that @Jamiec.  I did change it in the function still working as before with just 1 change enabling the button.

Comment: In which case please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, because as my link to jsfiddle above shows it works when i fixed your typos

Comment: Thank you @Jamiec.  I found the issue another function was getting in the way here.  I appreciate all your help.